# ¿Como puedo ajustar la posicion de ingreso de texto en JAVA?

Tags: java, cursor

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("SELECCIONE UN MODO PARA LA GENERACION DEL REPORTE:");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("1. MENSUAL");
                System.out.println("2. PERSONALIZADO");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("SELECCIONE UNA OPCION: ");
```

Yo deseo que al momento de seleccionar una opcion (la cual ya esta configurada mediante SWITCH) se pueda ver de la siguiente forma en pantalla:

```
SELECCIONE UNA OPCION: "aqui se digita la opcion"
```

Actualmente el cursor queda debajo del texto "SELECCIONE UNA OPCION".

¿Cómo puedo ajustar el cursor para que quede en frente del texto que yo desee? La app es desarrollada en modo consola, no tiene interfaz gráfica.

Answer (score 5):

Utiliza el método que no realiza salto de línea después de mostrar el mensaje

```
System.out.print("SELECCIONE UNA OPCION: ");
```

Mas información

[System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)